# Terminal message "Access control disabled"

Tags: 12.04, command-line, security

Every time I open up the terminal the message `access control disabled, clients can connect from any host` pops up in the first line.

Then the terminal behaves as usual, no errors at all. But this seems a security issue, and I'm not sure where it comes from.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

It started appearing while I was trying to resolve something related to video drivers, which are giving me a big headache.

I don't know what I did (copy-pasting terminal commands without even reading it, I know, I deserve this) or where to start looking for a solution...

Answer (score 1):

This error is produced by the `xhost` program that is used to allow or deny access to the X server for any host.
In other words, this is a tool used to block or allow the usage of the X Server by graphical application that could be ran remotely. As such, it can be a security problem as remote graphical application could be able to directly connect to your X Server and access other local resources.

It is like you have this command configured to run in one the profile file of the shell used. Check if you don't have the `xhost` command mentioned in one of the profile file :

- Globally, in `/etc/profile` and in any files under `/etc/profile.d`
- Locally, in your home directory in `.bashrc` (for Bash shell), `.profile` or any other shell's profile files.

More info about Xhost [at this link](http://www.leidinger.net/X/xhost.html).

Answer (score 1):

I know that is to late, but i will put here the solution for future reference. As normal user, you can do authorization for any other user to execute gui programs on your X session with the command

```
$ xhost +SI:localuser:<user name>
```

If you use sudo, this command is very usefull to authorizate root execute gui programs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

Unfortunately, I have no longer access to the system on which the error happened, so I can't check the solution. But thanks anyway!